# How to create a bill checker with Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

What I'm trying to do is to create a Google Sheet to check my internet bill, but something doesn't seem to work.

```
FROM        TO          TOT DAYS    PRICE CALCULATED        PRICE OF BILL
5/3/2020    30/4/2020   57          €  47.31                 €  47.23 
                    
                    
NOTE:                   
My Subscription Price per month      €  24.90           
Bill received                        €  47.23
```

Why there is difference between the price calculated by me and the price of the bill received by the provider?

Formula I Used:

```
TOT DAYS =SUM(B2-A2)+1
```

Price calculated `=SUM(C2*(24.9/30))`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe: The From date could be hiding a time element that is used in the calculation, but is not included in the display. For example, if you change your from date to be `2020-3-5 02:18` then it will change the calculated bill to €47.23

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]! I assume the Community-a-thon has started :)

Comment: It has! And I meant to post this from my sock, and used the wrong window :-/ nice to see you on your home turf

Comment: I've checked the TIME of all cells and they are all 00:00:00
And that maybe lead me to this discover:
I think it's an issue caused by the change of clock by the "Daylight Saving Time", and this is why there is a little difference, but the problem now, how i can calculate it knowing that there is the change of time during the night of 28 March?